# Customizing "The Events Calendar" "RSVP" form

Tags: wordpress, calendar, wordpress-plugin-creation

Thanks in advance.

After learning ["How to customize templates files"](https://theeventscalendar.com/knowledgebase/k/customizing-template-files-2/) in the **knowledgebase** in [theeventscalendar.com](https://theeventscalendar.com), I'm trying to find where to change the form for the RSVP: [RSVP FORM](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GXjgP.png).

The goal is to add a select with options (non-dynamicals) for the user to record.

The problem occurred when I tried to locate within the plugin where this information was found.

I went to `wp-content> plugins> event-tickets> src> views> registration` But I couldn't locate where to make the change, so I suspect it is not there. And that's **my request**: Could someone help me locate where to make the change?

Any idea to include this selection and that it appears reflected in the backend where the Attendees are reflected will be welcome.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use additional fields extension which will allow you to add many different form fields which get saved under the attendee's list.

You can see info on this here:

https://theeventscalendar.com/knowledgebase/k/pro-additional-fields/
https://theeventscalendar.com/blog/tips/how-to-leverage-event-calendar-pros-additional-fields-as-a-small-business/